# Rails app - admin attribute not showing up for users

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm probably missing something simple, but I added an admin boolean to my Users with a migration and ran rake db:migrate. I added the :admin to the user.rb file. When I go to the console and type User.find(1).admin it comes back nil, but if I just call User.find(1) it doesn't list admin in the attributes.

If I run 
    u = User.find(1)
    u.admin = true
    u.save

It shows as true, but then if I run User.find(1).admin again is says nil and still doesn't show up when I just call User.find(1)

My schema shows t.boolean "admin"

I'm using Devise, which could be part of the issue. Am I missing something here? I thought maybe it's a bad migration, but then I should get an error if I try to set the admin in the console.

Comment: Did you run rake db:migrate?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. Devise has moved the attributes from the user model to the application controller. I needed to add the :admin like this:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :firstname
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :lastname
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :admin
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :firstname
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :lastname
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :admin
 end
```